# Set one-to-one relationship id

Tags: java, spring-boot, one-to-one

I am having trouble with setting the city_id value for the one-to-one. I am using this code inside of my Person object.

```
 @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinColumn(name = "cityId", referencedColumnName = "id")
 private City city;
```

This code allows me to set a relationship with the city table if the city id exists in the person query. But, when I create a new Person query, I can't set a new city_id. So, my new query will always have a null value.

Comment: Please include the complete source code with more details

Comment: Try to add @GeneratedValue, for getting external id from DB into your field "id"